# Database mirroring with Mysql for Java Applications

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mirroring

Can anyone explain me the database mirroring, especially with mysql.

I have few questions

1. Do I have to create a connection on Java application to those databases (master db and slave dbs)? And is there a connection string for that or it is just a programmable part?
2. Do i also have to duplicate all my sql trasactions enable to take effect all database movements to both master and slave?
3. What if the master db is down, and the only connection is the slave, how can i patch the master db enable to be updated on records changed during the master is down?
4. Is it ok that the slave db is on the local host and the master is on server machine, or there are 2 server machine on which one is master and one is slave?
5. And how am i going to connect to those two databse(slave and master) using my java application which type of connection that if master is down automatically the slave connection will be use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) Do I have to create a connection on Java application to those databases (master db and slave dbs)? And is there a connection string for that or it is just a programmable part?

Yes. Typically you will create a connection to the master only if you need to write to the database. For read jobs you would use connections to one or more slaves so the master doesn't have to deal with that load. This is done programmatically, there is no connection string for this.
You could also look at [this link](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Proxy_RW_Splitting) which uses MySQL proxy to split the reads and writes transparently for your application. It should be noted that this is a proof of concept only

> 2) Do i also have to duplicate all my sql trasactions enable to take effect all database movements to both master and slave?

No, mysql replication will do this for you.

> 3) What if the master db is down, and the only connection is the slave, how can i patch the master db enable to be updated on records changed during the master is down?

The short answer is you can't. If you need highly available reads you should look at MySQL Cluster. A multiple master configuration might work as well.

> 4) Is it ok that the slave db is on the local host and the master is on server machine, or there are 2 server machine on which one is master and one is slave?

The master and slave machines can and should reside on different servers. It is unlikely that you would want to place the slaves on end-user machines, if that is what you mean by 'localhost'.

> 5) And how am i going to connect to those two databse(slave and master) using my java application which type of connection that if master is down automatically the slave connection will be use.

If all your reads come from the slave (or slaves), losing the master will not disrupt your reads, only your writes. If you have a single slave and it goes down, you could optionally fall back to using the master connection for reads.